# cost-complexity-pruning-path with pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees, pipelines, pruning

I'm using Kaggle's titanic set. I'm using pieplines and I'm trying to prune my decision tree and for that I want the cost_complexity_pruning_path. The last line of code produces the error:
   `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'male'`  
Do you know what I'm doing wrong? I have looked at [Sklearn: applying cost complexity pruning along with pipeline](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/84172/sklearn-applying-cost-complexity-pruning-along-with-pipeline) but that doesn't seem to be helping in my case

```
cat_vars = ['Sex','Embarked']
num_vars = ['Age']

num_pipe = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),('std_scaler', StandardScaler())])
cat_pipe = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),('ohe', OneHotEncoder())])

col_trans = ColumnTransformer([('numerical', num_pipe, num_vars),('categorical', cat_pipe, cat_vars)] ,remainder='passthrough')

final_pipe = Pipeline([('column_trans', col_trans), ('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))])
final_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

path = final_pipe.steps[1][1].cost_complexity_pruning_path(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `cost_complexity_pruning_path` refits the tree model on the data you provide before doing the pruning ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L576)), you need to preprocess the data first.  So this should do it:

```py
X_preproc = final_pipe[:-1].transform(X_train)
path = final_pipe.steps[-1][1].cost_complexity_pruning_path(X_preproc, y_train)
```

Comment: ...which I now see is basically the same answer as I provided in the linked question.  Oh well.

Comment: I tried your answer in the other question, but it didn't work, but using your answer here, it works fine. I guess the problem was that here I had more than one transformer before the tree which meant that I needed the final_pipe[:-1] instead of the final_pipe[-1] that I tried based on the question I linked to that you previously answered